# PHP: How to generate a GUID as char 22?

Tags: php, guid

I generate my GUIDs like this:

```
public static function getGUID(){
        if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
            return com_create_guid();
        }
        else {
            mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
            $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
            $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
            $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12);
            return $uuid;
        }
    }
```

But for the API I am using, I need to get an GUID as char 22. How do I do this?

It should look like this:

> 051MWsLH7jMaiuTyaRbC80

Comment: `from char 22`/`as char 22` Can you show what exactly you want? Simple example may be?

Comment: @vp_arth: Please see my edit.

Comment: `$uuid = substr($charid, 0, 22)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

22 char UUID is called XUID. see instructions how to make XUID from UUID [here](http://www.xuid.org/faq) also there is a link to PHP library to generate XUID

Comment: just ensure your `composer` phar is up to date to install this (installation broke with composer version 1.0 but worked with composer version 1.2-dev)